# Compile Error: Invalid bind expression type of Name for column of type String at line 4 column 34

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger CaseOwner on Case (before insert,before update) {
    for (Case CaseRecord : Trigger.New) {
     if (CaseRecord.Owner != null) {
       List<user> findDivision = [select id from user
                                    where name = :CaseRecord.Owner];
```

I know this may be a silly question. I am getting above compile error for the above code snippet. All i am trying is to get ID by matching name field from user with case record owner field and since case record owner is picklist, i am getting this error. Can someone help in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a picklist, it's a lookup field. A lookup field holds an ID, and also has an "sobject" component. You're trying to reference the SObject Name (Owner is a Name type of object), but you really wanted the ID, which is referenced as OwnerId. "sobject" references are always initially null in a trigger, unless you query for them. Finally, you should not query in a loop, as you'll hit governor limits.

Here's a modified version:

```
Map<id, user> users = new map<id, user>();
for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
  users.put(record.ownerid);
}
users.putAll([SELECT Division FROM User WHERE Id = :users.keySet()]);
for(Case record: Trigger.new) {
  if(users.get(record.ownerid) != null) {
    record.Owner_Division__c = users.get(record.ownerid).division;
  }
}
```

Note that, because of assignment rules, the value in OwnerId may not be correct in a before trigger, or even an after trigger, so you may want to instead call a future method, use a workflow rule or process, or possibly even a formula field.